# Словарь в Python, расширение значений ключа

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, списки

**Каким образом/методом можно расширить значения объекта по ключу в словаре, есть ли универсальный метод или способ для этого без шаманства?** 
К примеру расширить значения в словаре с условием, описанном на [Stepic](https://stepic.org/lesson/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8-3373/step/5?unit=956):

```
def update_dictionary(d, key, value):
    if key in d:
        d[key] =+ (value)
    else:
        d.update({key*2:value})
    print (d)
d = {1:2, 2:3, 3:4}
update_dictionary(d, 1, -1)
update_dictionary(d, 2, 2)
update_dictionary(d, 5, 10)
update_dictionary(d, 1, 21)
```

- *Код написан неверно, он не работает как должен, написан для примера.*

На выходе получается `{1: 21, 2: 2, 3: 4, 10: 10}`
, но в итоге нужно не полное замещение значений ключа а его расширение `{1: -1, 21, key: value1, value2...}` . 
**Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?**

Comment: Я никого не прошу решать задание или комментировать данный кусок кода, я сам отлично справлюсь, если будут даны пояснения и варианты по моему вопросу.

Comment: вопрос не ясен. Уберите упоминание внешнего ресурса. Опишите своими **словами** (а не с помощью неработающего кода) какое преобразование над словарём вы хотите произвести и приведите пример что на входе, что на выходе (`{1: -1, 21, key: value1, value2...}` не является корректной константой для словаря в Питоне, возможно вы имели ввиду `{1: [2, -1, 21], 2:[3,2], 3:4, 10:10}`).

Comment: Вопрос выведен в заголовке, а так же в теле выделен **ЖИРНЫМ**,  все остальное для примера указано, даже сводка имеется по коду, все схематично описано для понимания вопроса, если вы обладаете знанием по данному вопросу, прошу рассказать, а не устраивать дискуссии по моему вопросу, я жду ответов как от @andy.37, а не минусования и дополнительный вопросов по моему вопросу, я доступно описал мою задачу (напоминаю - **ЖИРНЫМ**).

Comment: То что у Вас жирным описано не является конкретным вопросом. *"расширить значения объекта по ключю в словаре"* слишком обширно -- не хватает деталей -- необходимо уточнить вопрос. [Будьте вежливы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Для этого схематичное описание и в конце и ожидаемый итог: '{1: -1, 21, key: value1, value2...}', первый объект словаря и последующие ключи и значения, которые добавились в процессе расширения словаря, а в частности значений по конкретному ключу. Не хочу оскорбить никого, я жду помощи, разъяснений по данному вопросу, так как хочу понимать какими способами еще можно данный вопрос реализовать.

Comment: @akaTaniS, то, что Вы приводите в качестве ожидаемого итога противоречит синтаксису используемого языка.

Comment: Не спорю, такого в этом ЯП не может быть, это схематичное описание словаря по элементам как последовательности, каким словарь и является(ключ: значение), что бы понимать какого результата я хочу добиться, @andy.37 меня понял и дал пару хороших вариантов. Как могу объясняю )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
def extend_dictionary(d, key, value):
   if key in d:
      if isinstance(d[key], list):
         d[key].append(value)
      else:
         d[key] = [d[key], value]
   else:
      d[key] = value
```

или так:

```
if key in d:
   try:
      d[key].append(value)
   except AttributeError:
      d[key] = [d[key], value]
else:
   d[key] = value
```

---

Вам нужно в первую очередь для себя понять, что именно Вы понимаете под "расширением" значения словаря. Просто можно придумать миллион способов - упаковка в список: `[d[key], newvalue]`, в кортеж: `(d[key], newvalue)` или `d[key] + (newvalue,)` если d[key] - уже кортеж, в специальный класс типа `Appendable` с реализованным методом append, да хоть в строку `str(d[key]) + ',' + str(newvalue)`, можно даже в словарь, счатающий повторения совпадающих значений: `{1: {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 1}, 2: {'x': 1, 1: 2}}`. В конце концов тривиальное `d[key] += newvalue` - тоже можно назвать расширением.

---

Вот это: `d[2 * key] = ...` мне представляется крайне неудачным, т.к. что мы будем делать если ключ `2 * key in d --> True`? На 3 умножать?

---

Дополню ответ (за настырность). Вы часто употребляете термин "последовательность" - `value1, value2, ...`. Надо понять, что именно является последовательностью. В python реализовано несколько видов встроенных последовательностей - это список `list`, кортеж `tuple`, множество `set`, в известном смысле словарь `dict`. В С - только массив (прямых аналогов в питоне нет). В других языках другие. Можно реализовать свою последовательность:

```
class MySophisticatedSequence:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.current = 0
        if self.value < self.current:
            raise ValueError

    def append(self, newvalue):
        self.value += newvalue

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value < self.value

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.current > self.value:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current += 1
            return self.current - 1


a = MySophisticatedSequence(4)
print 3 in a
print 6 in a
a.append(5)
print 6 in a
for i in a:
    print i
```

Это хоть и достаточно бессмысленная, но тоже последовательность, в которую можно паковать value1, value2 и т.д. (вытащить обратно будет непросто - это да)

Comment: 1- пожалуйста, не используйте такие ужасы как `type(d[key]) == type([])` в вашем коде никогда. Можно использовать `list` и в целом лучше избегать явных проверок типов в Питоне, но если они нужны, то используйте что-то вроде `isinstance(.., MutableSequence)`. Можно ещё написать: `try: d[key] += [value] except TypeError: d[key] = [value] except KeyError: d[2 * key] = value` 2- `else` часть возможно должна быть: `d[2 * key] = value`.

Comment: @jfs 1 - согласен, поспешил, 2 - особенно удачно получится если есть ключи 1 и 2 ('a' и 'aa').

Comment: Возможно сделать из словаря вида `{key: value1}` _(код)_ `{key: value1, value2, value3...}` без создания списка?

Comment: @akaTaniS, еще раз, что Вы понимаете под `value1, value2, ...`?

Comment: Очень длинный и содержательный ответ, спасибо! Под `value` я имею в виду значение ключа как `{1: -1, 21}` (-1 и 21 - `value`). И я ни разу не упомянул про **последовательность** для этого, как вы заметили, имеются другие типы данных, но спасибо за комментарий.

Comment: И да, в примере `код` немного кривой и выводит кривой ответ, я его писал в отладчике, что бы понимать, как будет вести себя словарь и что с ним можно делать и как работать, встал вопрос, на который не смог найти ответа в просторах сети, пришел к вам )

Answer (score 2):

```
key_val = [0, 1, 2], [10, 11, 12]

dt = {tuple(kv): kv for kv in key_val}
print(1, dt)

key_val[0].append(3)
key_val[-1].pop(-1)
print(2, dt)
```

1 {(0, 1, 2): [0, 1, 2], (10, 11, 12): [10, 11, 12]}

2 {(0, 1, 2): [0, 1, 2, 3], (10, 11, 12): [10, 11]}

Answer (score 0):

Внимательно прочтите задание. Вам нужно в качестве значений словаря использовать списки:

```
dct = {
    'key1': [1, 2, 3],
    'key2': [4, 5, 6],
    'key3: []  # Пустой список
}
```

Таким образом "расширить значения объекта" можно просто добавив с список, соответствующий ключу, дополнительный элемент через `append`.

Comment: А вы прочтите внимательно мой вопрос выделенный специально **жирным**, прежде чем давать ответы. Вскользь брошенный код и комментарий к нему не несет практически никакой полезной информации, я знаю, что можно что можно сделать через списки, однако вопрос звучал иначе.